# SWT issues in Aligning a button

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

I have written a small program which has 2 list view and a button to select and unselect the selected combinations. The issue is I am unable to align the buttons to the center of the column.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, true));
    GridData data = new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH);

    // Creating Label
    new Label(shell, SWT.NONE).setText("This is a plain Text");
    new Label(shell, SWT.NONE).setText("");
    new Label(shell, SWT.NONE).setText("This is a plain Text");
    // Create a single-selection list
    List single = new List(shell, SWT.BORDER | SWT.SINGLE | SWT.V_SCROLL);
    single.setLayoutData(data);

    // Add the items, one by one
    for (int i = 0, n = ITEMS.length; i < n; i++) {
        single.add(ITEMS[i]);
    }
    single.setSelection(0);

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Button button1=new Button(shell, SWT.ARROW | SWT.RIGHT);

    Group first = new Group(shell, SWT.CENTER);
    first.setLayout(new RowLayout(SWT.VERTICAL));
    Button button1 = new Button(first, SWT.NONE);

    // GridData bdata = new GridData(GridData.HORIZONTAL_ALIGN_BEGINNING);

    Button button3 = new Button(first, SWT.PUSH);
    // button3.setLayoutData(bdata);
    button1.setText("Select    ");
    button3.setText("UnSelect");

    //////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Create a single-selection list
    List single2 = new List(shell, SWT.BORDER | SWT.SINGLE | SWT.V_SCROLL);
    single2.setLayoutData(data);
    single2.add("");

    single2.setSelection(0);

    shell.open();

    System.out.println(single.getItem(single.getSelectionIndex()));

    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

Actual Output:

[image]

Expected Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to reuse `GridData` on more that one control, this will cause problems because layout information is stored in the data. You must use a new `GridData` for each control. So:

```
List single = new List(shell, SWT.BORDER | SWT.SINGLE | SWT.V_SCROLL);
single.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));


List single2 = new List(shell, SWT.BORDER | SWT.SINGLE | SWT.V_SCROLL);
single2.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
```

To centre the buttons set `GridData` on the `Group`:

```
Group first = new Group(shell, SWT.NONE);
first.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.CENTER, SWT.CENTER, true, true));
```

This `GridData` requests horizontal and vertical centering.

To make the buttons both the same width use `GridLayout` for the group and use horizontal fill and grab space:

```
first.setLayout(new GridLayout());

Button button1 = new Button(first, SWT.NONE);
button1.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false));

Button button3 = new Button(first, SWT.PUSH);
button3.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false));
```

Note that the using `GridData.FILL_BOTH` and similar constants is no longer recommended.

Comment: thank you for reviewing my code.  I have another Question, How do I ensure both the buttons are of equal width. As of now, I have given spaces, I know that is not the correct way to do that.

Comment: Added the code to make the buttons the same width to the answer